# Is there a way of using relative adress with websockets?

Tags: websocket, elm

Is there some easy way of using relative address with websockets? Something like:

```
WebSocket.listen "<ws://localhost:8080/api>" Msg ->  
   WebSocket.listen "<ws://api>" Msg
```

Or do I have to create a task to retrieve `window.location.host` on start and use it to construct the url?

Comment: Just for personal interest I googled elm+websocket and found [an article that might help you](https://medium.com/@zenitram.oiram/a-beginners-guide-to-websockets-in-elm-and-crystal-8f510c28eb61). At the end it describes how to use flags for setting the WS address at start time. So, no need for a task, flags are relatively simple. Note thought that the article is for earlier version of Elm, so if you're using 0.19, the syntax will be bit different. The official Elm docs have instructions on flags.

Comment: @kaskelotti The WebSocket module doesn't exist for 0.19 yet, so no chance of that (unfortunately).

Comment: @GarethLatty That was just a side note. Flags exist in previous versions of Elm also, the syntax is just different. Or did I misunderstood you somehow?

Comment: @kaskelotti My point was that since the OP is using the `WebSocket` module, they won't be using 0.19.